# Are the adjective "wise" and the suffix "-wise" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, suffixes

Are they linked, or have they arisen seperatedly and/or without connection?

Comment: Have you looked this up in any dictionary or etymological references?

Comment: I only found etymological information regarding the adjective. @TrevorD

Answer (score 5):

The Oxford English Dictionary indicates that in English *-wise* branched off from the noun *wise*, in the sense of "in what wise" (in what manner). The relevant entry under "[wise, n.1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229496)" describes *-wise* functioning as a noun qualified by an adjective or another noun, much as we might say *red car* or *diesel car*. Over time the compounds became single words or expressions and *-wise* was interpreted as a suffix. (Imagine if redcar and dieselcar became words and -car were generalized to mean "a vehicular conveyance.") The entry explains:

> II. Old English *wíse* manner, fashion, like the cognate forms in other Germanic languages (see the respective sections below), was used in various kinds of adverbial expressions meaning ‘in such-and-such a manner, way, or respect’, in which it was qualified by an adjective or a noun with or without a governing preposition. Several of these expressions, with others formed on their pattern in later periods, have survived as simple words, e.g. *anywise, crosswise, leastwise, likewise, nowise, otherwise, slantwise*, in which *-wise* has the appearance of a suffix, and, in so far as it could or can still be freely combined with an adjective or a noun (as in senses 1b, 5b), it has actually performed the function of a suffix. The free use of the various forms, i.e. apart from the established simple words, is now only archaic except in sense 5b.

So something like *in like wise* became *likewise*, and with the influence of words like it, *-wise* was perceived as a suffix.

The noun *wise* meaning "manner" and the adjective *wise* meaning "sound judgment* are close in form and history. In *[Word Hoard](https://books.google.com/books?id=JK-KQgAACAAJ&dq=Stephen%20Barney%20word%20hoard&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-5pqT0IziAhUIU98KHS8qCeMQ6AEIKjAA)*, Old English scholar Stephen Barney records "*wīs* (adj) 'WISE' " right before "*wīse* (wk.f., and suffix) 'manner, way' " in the word group 29 headed by *witan* ("know"). They also have similar form in nearby and previous languages to Old English. Compare the adjective *wise* meaning sound of judgment, as [adopted from the OED "wise, adj. (n.3 and adv.)"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229495):

> Old English **wís** = Old Frisian, Old Saxon, Old High German (Middle Low
>   German, Middle Dutch, Middle High German) **wîs** , (Dutch **wijs** , German
>   **weis** in phrase einen weis machen ), Old Norse **víss** (Swedish, Danish
>   vis ), Gothic **weis** (in compounds) < Old Germanic ***wīsaz** < pre-Germanic
>   ***wīttos** , < Indo-European **weid**- (see wit v.1) + participial suffix -to-.

to *wise* meaning manner or way, which influenced *-wise* ([OED again](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229496)):

> Old English **wíse** weak feminine (rarely **wís** strong feminine) manner,
>   mode, condition, thing, affair, cause, reason, (occasionally) song =
>   Old Frisian **wîs** , Old Saxon **wîsa** weak and strong (Middle Low German
>   **wîse** , **wîs** , Middle Dutch **wîze** , **wijs** , Dutch **wijze** ), Old High German
>   **wîsa** , and **wîs** manner, custom, tune (Middle High German **wîse** , German
>   weise ), Old Norse **vísa** weak feminine stanza, ***vís** manner in öðruvís
>   otherwise (Swedish **visa** , Danish **vise** song; also Swedish, Danish **vis**
>   way, manner) < Old Germanic ***wīsōn**- , ***wīsō** : < **wit**- wit v.1 (for the
>   sense compare the cognate Greek εἶδος form, shape, kind, state of
>   things, course of action).

From Middle Low German *wîs* to close pairings in Old Norse, Dutch, and other languages, these would have been distinct but closely related words back to at least Old Germanic, and it's possible people have interchanged the two words and meanings. However, in English, *-wise* is not directly related to the *wise* in "a wise person."

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the divergence in meaning was very early. [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=wise) lists a noun sense of *wise* that provides the origin of the modern suffix:

> "way of proceeding, manner," Old English *wise* "way, fashion, custom, habit, manner; condition, state, circumstance," from Proto-Germanic **wison* "appearance, form, manner" (see **wise** (adj.)). Compare Old Saxon *wisa*, Old Frisian *wis*, Danish *vis*, Middle Dutch *wise*, Dutch *wijs*, Old High German *wisa*, German *Weise* "way, manner." Most common in English now as a word-forming element (as in **likewise**, **clockwise**); the adverbial *-wise* has been used thus since Old English.

These origins are different from the origin of the adjective sense referring to knowledge, which comes from Proto-Germanic **wissaz*.

However it does hint at an earlier common derivation:

> For sense evolution from "to see" to "way of proceeding," compare cognate Greek *eidos* "form, shape, kind," also "course of action." Ground sense is "to see/know the way."

Comment: That first sentence in the etymonline entry says that the suffix '-wise' is cognate to the Proto-Germanic adjective that 'wise' comes from.

Comment: While it cross-references to the adjective, most of the etymology list there is different. E.g. it says that comes from Proto-Germanic *\*wissaz*, not *\*wison*.

Comment: Yeah, those are cognate.